# Showing Django comments after submission with ajax

Tags: ajax, django, comments

I implemented Django ajax comment submission in my app using Nick Carroll's method [here](http://ca.rroll.net/2009/05/10/improving-django-comments-user-experience-with-ajax/).  I'd like the user that posted the comment, date of submission and comment to appear on the page using ajax after the server has received and saved it.  What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright this is kind of a hackerish way to go about this, but I think I've figured out a decent solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function bindPostCommentHandler() {
        $('#comment_form form input.submit-preview').remove();
        $('#comment_form form').submit(function() {
            var comment_text = $('#id_comment').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#comment_form form').serialize(),
                url: "{% comment_form_target %}",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(html, textStatus) {
                    $('#comment_form form').fadeTo(500, 0, function(){
                        $(this).remove();
                    });

                    var today = new Date();
                    var dd = today.getDate();
                    var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
                    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                    if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd} if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm} var today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
                    var comment = "<div class='comment'><h4>User " + "\"{{ user.username }}\"" + " Rating <small>" + today + "</small></h4>" + comment_text + "</div><hr />";
                    $(comment).hide().prependTo("#comments_loc").fadeIn(1000);  
                    bindPostCommentHandler();
                },
                 error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#comment_form form').replaceWith('Your comment was unable to be posted at this time.  We apologize for the inconvenience.');
                 }
           });
        return false;
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    bindPostCommentHandler();
});
</script>
```

I'm relatively new to javascript so I put this together with what little I know.  Feel free to leave some comments if you think this could be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's post method to post the comment to server and on successful response,display the comment on the page from the success call back function.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function bindPostCommentHandler() {
        $('#comment_form form input.submit-preview').remove();
        $('#comment_form form').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#comment_form form').serialize(),
                url: "{% comment_form_target %}",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(html, textStatus) {
                    $('#comment_form form').replaceWith(html);
                     $('.comt_message').show();
                    bindPostCommentHandler();
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#comment_form form').replaceWith('Your comment was unable to be posted at this time.  We apologise for the inconvenience.');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        bindPostCommentHandler();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I understand that much, but how would you get the comment information to load into that div?  I must be missing something big here...